# Determine the value of n that will cause the following series to diverge and converge.

Tags: real-analysis

Determine the value of $n\in \mathbb{R}$ that will cause the following series to converge and diverge:

$$\sum_k^\infty\frac{\sin k}{k^n}$$

It is obvious that when n is more than 1 this series will converge by comparison test. When n =0, it will diverge by n term test. So the main concern is between $-\infty$ and 1(including 1).

Comment: **Hint:** Compare it to the [Dirichlet $\eta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eta_function), which converges for all $n>0$ through the [alternating series test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, this series converges for all $n > 0$.  One way to show that this is the case is the [Dirichlet Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).  In particular, since there exists an $M>0$ such that $\left|\sum_{k=1}^N \sin k\right| < M$ for each $N$ and since $1/k^n \to 0$, the series must converge.

One way to find a bound $M$ for $\left|\sum_{k=1}^N \sin k\right|$ is by using Euler's formula.  That is, we note that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^N \sin k\right| = \left|\Im\left(\sum_{k = 1}^N e^{ik} \right)\right| = 
\left|\Im\left(e^{i} \frac{e^{iN}-1}{e^{i}-1}\right)\right|
\leq
|e^{i}| \frac{|e^{iN}|+|1|}{|e^{i}-1|} = \frac{2}{(\cos(1) -1)^2 + \sin^2(1)}
$$

Comment: if sum sin k is bounded, doesn't that mean that sum sin k is convergent? But I thought since lim sin k when k tends to infinity is not 0 so by n term test, it is divergent? What's wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: @user136266 $\sum \sin k$ bounded doesn't imply it converges. This is because $\sin k$ doesn't have same sign.

Comment: ok thanks i just figured that out too

Comment: what about k < 0?

Comment: @user136266 Do you mean $\sum_{k = -N}^\infty\frac{\sin k}{k^n}$, or something else?

Comment: sorry i typed wrongly, i meant n<0

Comment: @user136266 a sum $\sum a_k$ can only converge if $a_k \to 0$.  If $n<0$, then $k^{-n}\,\sin k$ will not approach $0$ as $k \to \infty$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom the same argument does not apply to if we are to determine if the series converge absolutely right? In fact, i think it does not converge absolutely. How can I prove this? Do you have any idea?

Comment: The same argument applies.  If $a_k$ does not approach $0$, $\sum a_k$ cannot converge conditionally, let alone absolutely.  Remember that any sequence converges conditionally if it converges absolutely.